# PHP - ID generator//not working on linux

Tags: php, linux

I have made an "ID generator" for a website known as xat now this fully works on any up to date windows machine. But I do not understand why when I run it on a linux Debian server I get:

```
root@vps:/idgen# php get.php
[3:45:42 PM] Connected to MySQL server
[3:45:42 PM] Starting ID Generator With 0 IDs to begin with.
PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /idgen/get.php on line 70
root@vps:/idgen#
```

(I am new to linux machines. I did some research but till don't understand it :L my code is very long. Its

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_error', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$idGen = new IDGenerator;
$loop = 1;
while(true)
{
    switch(@$argv[1]) {
        case '0':
        default:
            $list = fopen('proxies.txt', 'r');
            while(!feof($list))
            {
                $proxy = fgets($list);
                $idGen->generate($proxy);
            }
            fclose($list);
        break;
    }
    $loop++;
    usleep(50000);
    $idGen->report('Starting loop #'.$loop);
}

class IDGenerator
{
    public $sql = NULL;
    public $one = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
    public $two = array('11','22','33','44','55','66','77','88','99','00');
    public $three = array('111','222','333','444','555','666','777','888','999','000');
    public $four = array('0000','1010','1111','1212','1313','1414','1515','1616','1717','1818','1919','2020','2121','2222','2323','2424','2525','2626','2727','2828','2929','3030','3131','3232','3333','3434','3535','3636','3737','3838','3939','4040','4141','4242','4343','4444','4545','4646','4747','4848','4949','5050','5151','5252','5353','5454','5555','5656','5757','5858','5959','6060','6161','6262','6363','6464','6565','6666','6767','6868','6969','7070','7171','7272','7373','7474','7575','7676','7777','7878','7979','8080','8181','8282','8383','8484','8585','8686','8787','8888','8989','9090','9191','9292','9393','9494','9595','9696','9797','9898','9999');
    public $five = array('00000','10101','11111','12121','13131','14141','15151','16161','17171','18181','19191','20202','21212','22222','23232','24242','25252','26262','27272','28282','29292','30303','31313','32323','33333','34343','35353','36363','37373','38383','39393','40404','41414','42424','43434','44444','45454','46464','47474','48484','49494','50505','51515','52525','53535','54545','55555','56565','57575','58585','59595','60606','61616','62626','63636','64646','65656','66666','67676','68686','69696','70707','71717','72727','73737','74747','75757','76767','77777','78787','79797','80808','81818','82828','83838','84848','85858','86868','87878','88888','89898','90909','91919','92929','93939','94949','95959','96969','97979','98989','99999');
    public $six = array('000000','101010','111111','121212','131313','141414','151515','161616','171717','181818','191919','202020','212121','222222','232323','242424','252525','262626','272727','282828','292929','303030','313131','323232','333333','343434','353535','363636','373737','383838','393939','404040','414141','424242','434343','444444','454545','464646','474747','484848','494949','505050','515151','525252','535353','545454','555555','565656','575757','585858','595959','606060','616161','626262','636363','646464','656565','666666','676767','686868','696969','707070','717171','727272','737373','747474','757575','767676','777777','787878','797979','808080','818181','828282','838383','848484','858585','868686','878787','888888','898989','909090','919191','929292','939393','949494','959595','969696','979797','989898','999999');
    public $seven = array('0000000','1010101','1111111','1212121','1313131','1414141','1515151','1616161','1717171','1818181','1919191','2020202','2121212','2222222','2323232','2424242','2525252','2626262','2727272','2828282','2929292','3030303','3131313','3232323','3333333','3434343','3535353','3636363','3737373','3838383','3939393','4040404','4141414','4242424','4343434','4444444','4545454','4646464','4747474','4848484','4949494','5050505','5151515','5252525','5353535','5454545','5555555','5656565','5757575','5858585','5959595','6060606','6161616','6262626','6363636','6464646','6565656','6666666','6767676','6868686','6969696','7070707','7171717','7272727','7373737','7474747','7575757','7676767','7777777','7878787','7979797','8080808','8181818','8282828','8383838','8484848','8585858','8686868','8787878','8888888','8989898','9090909','9191919','9292929','9393939','9494949','9595959','9696969','9797979','9898989','9999999');
    public $eight = array('00000000','10101010','11111111','12121212','13131313','14141414','15151515','16161616','17171717','18181818','19191919','20202020','21212121','22222222','23232323','24242424','25252525','26262626','27272727','28282828','29292929','30303030','31313131','32323232','33333333','34343434','35353535','36363636','37373737','38383838','39393939','40404040','41414141','42424242','43434343','44444444','45454545','46464646','47474747','48484848','49494949','50505050','51515151','52525252','53535353','54545454','55555555','56565656','57575757','58585858','59595959','60606060','61616161','62626262','63636363','64646464','65656565','66666666','67676767','68686868','69696969','70707070','71717171','72727272','73737373','74747474','75757575','76767676','77777777','78787878','79797979','80808080','81818181','82828282','83838383','84848484','85858585','86868686','87878787','88888888','89898989','90909090','91919191','92929292','93939393','94949494','95959595','96969696','97979797','98989898','99999999');
    public $nine = array('000000000','101010101','111111111','121212121','131313131','141414141','151515151','161616161','171717171','181818181','191919191','202020202','212121212','222222222','232323232','242424242','252525252','262626262','272727272','282828282','292929292','303030303','313131313','323232323','333333333','343434343','353535353','363636363','373737373','383838383','393939393','404040404','414141414','424242424','434343434','444444444','454545454','464646464','474747474','484848484','494949494','505050505','515151515','525252525','535353535','545454545','555555555','565656565','575757575','585858585','595959595','606060606','616161616','626262626','636363636','646464646','656565656','666666666','676767676','686868686','696969696','707070707','717171717','727272727','737373737','747474747','757575757','767676767','777777777','787878787','797979797','808080808','818181818','828282828','838383838','848484848','858585858','868686868','878787878','888888888','898989898','909090909','919191919','929292929','939393939','949494949','959595959','969696969','979797979','989898989','999999999');
    public $proxy;
    public $cp = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        include('database.class.php');
        $this->sql = new Database($this);
        $this->report('Connected to MySQL Server');

        $nc = number_format( $this->sql->countRows('ids WHERE sold=0') );
        $this->report('Starting ID Generator With '.$nc.' IDs to begin with.');
    }

    public function generate($ip='111.111.111.111',$port=1, $elapsed=0) {
        if( ( $elapsed - time() ) >= 0  && $elapsed != 0) {
            //This causes MAJOR terminal/CMD flood.
    //      $this->report('Proxy: '.$ip.':'.$port.' will be trying again in '.$this->sec2hms($elapsed-time()));
            return;
        }
        $this->cp = array(
            'ip'    =>  $ip,
            'port'  =>  $port
        );
        $proxy = $ip.':'.$port;

        $tries = 0;
        $xData = '';
        $timeout = 3;
    //  echo "Tries -> ";
        while($xData=='' && $tries < 3) {
            $ch = curl_init(); //curl init :D
            curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_URL,                'http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/auser3.php?t='.rand(100000000000,1000000000000000000000000000000000)); //url
            curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_PROXY,              $proxy);
            curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,     1);
            curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,     $timeout);
            curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,            $timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $rdata = $data;
            if(@$data{0} == '<') { 
                return;//Bad Proxy Detected.
            }
            if(strpos($data, 'Not Found') != FALSE) { 
                $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0';
            }
            if($data != '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0') {
                if(strpos($data, '&k2=0') != FALSE) { 
                    $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0';
                } else {
                    $xData = $data;
                }
            } else {
                echo $data."\n";
            }
            $tries++;
            }

        if($xData=='') {
            return;//Dead Proxy
        }
        if (strlen($data) < 50 && $data) {
            $this->check($data);
        }
    }
    public function sec2hms($sec, $padHours = false) {
        @$hms = "";
        @$days = intval($sec/86400);
        if($days > 0 ) {
            if($days == 1) {
                @$hms .= (($padHours)?str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':':@$days.' Day');
            } else {
                @$hms .= (($padHours)?str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':':@$days.' Days');
            }
        }
        @$sec-= ($days*86400);
        @$hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
        if($hours > 0) {
            if($days > 0) { @$s = ', '; }
            if($hours == 1) {
                @$hms .= @$s.(($padHours)?str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':':@$hours.' Hour');
            } else {
                @$hms .= @$s.(($padHours)?str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':':@$hours.' Hours');
            }
        }
        @$minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
        if($minutes > 0) {
            if($hours > 0) { @$d = ', '; }
            if($minutes == 1) {
                @$hms .= @$d.str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' Minute';
            } else {
                @$hms .= @$d.str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' Minutes';
            }
        }
        @$seconds = intval($sec % 60);
        if($seconds > 0) {
            if($minutes > 0) { @$p = ', '; }
            if($seconds == 1) {
                @$hms .= @$p.str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' Second';
            } else {
                @$hms .= @$p.str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' Seconds';
            }
        }

        return @$hms;
    }
    public function report($data) {
        $time = date('g:i:s A', time());
        echo "[$time] $data\n";
    }

    public function rwrite($data) {
        $auser = $this->idFix($data);

        $check = $this->CheckForID($auser['UserId']);

        if($check) {
            if(str_replace(' ', '', $auser['UserId'])!='') {
                $this->report($auser['UserId'].' already exists in the database.');
            }
            return;
        }

        $auser['rare'] = true;
        $auser['price'] = $this->determinePrice($auser['UserId']);
        $auser['reglink'] = 'http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$auser['UserId'].'&k2='.$auser['k2'].'&mode=1';
        $auser['added'] = date('l, F jS Y g:i:s A');

        $this->sql->insert('ids', $auser);

        $nc = number_format( $this->sql->countRows('ids WHERE sold=0') );

        $this->report($auser['UserId'].' added as a rare id, we have '.$nc.' ids now.');
    }

    public function write($data) {
        $auser = $this->idFix($data);

        $check = $this->CheckForID($auser['UserId']);

        if($check) {
            if(str_replace(' ', '', $auser['UserId'])!='') {
                $this->report($auser['UserId'].' already exists in the database.');
            }
            return;
        }

        $auser['rare'] = false;
        $auser['added'] = date('l, F jS Y g:i:s A');
        $auser['price'] = $this->determinePrice($auser['UserId']);
        $auser['reglink'] = 'http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$auser['UserId'].'&k2='.$auser['k2'].'&mode=1';

        $this->sql->insert('ids', $auser);

        $nc = number_format( $this->sql->countRows('ids WHERE sold=0') );

        $this->report($auser['UserId'].' added as a normal id, we have '.$nc.' ids now.');
    }
    public function determinePrice($id='0') {
        if($id=='0' || !is_numeric($id)) {
            return '0';//0 xats cuz of no id.
        }
        $price = 100;//Start the bid off at 100 xats, NO FREE IDS.
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->nine)    ) {
            $price = $price + 900;// never mind that, make it 1k
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->eight)   ) {
            $price = $price + 800;
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->seven)   ) {
            $price = $price + 700;
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->six)     ) {
            $price = $price + 600;
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->five)    ) {
            $price = $price + 500;
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->four)    ) {
            $price = $price + 150;
        } else
        if (    $this->strposa($id, $this->three)   ) {
            $price = $price + 20;
        }
        return $price;
    }
    public function idFix($data='&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0')
    {
        if($data=='') { $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0'; }
        $user = explode('&', $data);
        return array(
            'UserId'=> str_replace('UserId=', '', @$user[1]),
            'k1' => str_replace('k1=', '', @$user[2]),
            'k2'=> str_replace('k2=', '', @$user[3])
        );
    }
    public function randomString($chars=32) {
        $letters = range('a','z');
        $caps = range('A', 'Z');
        $numbers = range(0, 9);
        $array = array_merge(range('a','z'), array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range(0,9)));
        for($x=0;$x<=100;$x++) {
            shuffle($array);//shuffle it up really good =D
        }
        $i = 0;
        $ch = '';
        for($index=0; $index<$chars; $index++) {
            $ch .= $array[ array_rand($array) ];
        }
        return $ch;
    }
    public function CheckForID($id=0)
    {
        if($id==0) return true;
        $check = $this->sql->select('*', 'ids', 'UserId='.$id);
        if(!$check)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function check($data='&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0') {
        if($data=='') { $data = '&UserId=0&k1=0&k2=0'; }
        $auser = $this->idFix($data);
        $this->storage($auser['UserId'], $data);    
    }

    public function storage($id, $data) {
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->nine) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data) {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->eight) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data)    {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->seven) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data)    {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->six) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data)  {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->five) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data) {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->four) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data) {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else
        if ($this->strposa($id,$this->three) && strlen($data) < 50 && $data)    {
            $this->rwrite($data);
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->write($data);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function reset() {
        die('restart me!');
    }

    public function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=1) {
        $chr = array();
        foreach($needles as $needle) {
            $res = strpos($haystack, $needle);
            if ($res !== false)
            {
                $chr[$needle] = $res;
            }
        }
        if(empty($chr))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return min($chr);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message to the question. The screenshot doesn't add any value, it just makes the question ungoogleable.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP fatal error actually has nothing whatsoever to do with Linux itself, it's the cURL extension that's missing from PHP.

To get back to the Debian side of things, to install the extension, run this in a command line / terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Note: Don't EVER copy-paste stuff from the internet into your console. You could be copying hidden text as well and potentially compromise your system. Go ahead and type it.

Comment: Heh, I'd never thought of copying hidden text. I guess the best compromise is to paste it into a text editor first, so you can see exactly what you've got, but don't have to faff about getting the spelling right...